# Should for loops only be used as iteration loops?

Tags: for-loop, while-loop, iteration

**EDIT :** I know how to use for loops / what I can use them for.  I'm asking the community your opinions on when certain usages of for loops are good / bad.

Just a general programming question:

> Should for loops only be used for iteration?

Note that iteration here is a very vaugly defined term- basically what I mean by it is the traditional `for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)` and variants on this.

Ex.:

You should / shouldn't use for loops for a counter:

`for (; keepGoing(); count++)` vs `while (keepGoing) { count++ }`

Some languages may also have certain caveats or different usage patterns too.  Without getting too particular, I'm looking at the question from a C++ / C# / Java usage pattern.

Things to consider:

- Ease of coding.
- Readability of code.
- Likelyhood of causing a bug (i.e. are off-by-one errors more common with certain for-loop usage or while loop usage).

Comment: @jfairbank Is this your homework?

Comment: No, not homework.  See my edit.  I know how to use for loops / while loops- I was just wondering what the community thinks about when you should use certain 'types' of for loops vs. their while loop counter parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a loop also for counters, they are also some kind of iteration.

You should however avoid loops like this:

```
for(;;){
}
```

or

```
while(true){
}
```

Also try to avoid continue and break statments in the loop, as they make the code hard to read and to debug.

Answer (score 1):

The only big sin in using a for loop is modifying the counter variable. That creates very difficult to maintain code.

Other than that a for loop does not guarantee the loop will execute once. Only a `do`loop can assure that. If that is not an issue then it becomes a matter of personal taste and style.